# Is there any quick way to implement a Material-UI theme?

Tags: material-ui, react-admin

I am aware of custom theming process within react-admin.

I was wondering if in react-admin it is possible to implement a custom theme without needing to go component by component and theming them ourselves. Something like for example Material Ui premium themes [(see here)](https://material-ui.com/store/items/devias-kit-pro/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, definitely. You can pass a custom `theme` to the `<Admin>` component:

```
const App = () => (
    <Admin theme={myTheme} dataProvider={simpleRestProvider('http://path.to.my.api')}>
        // ...
    </Admin>
);
```

Here is an example custom `theme`:

```
import { defaultTheme } from 'react-admin';
import merge from 'lodash/merge';
import indigo from '@material-ui/core/colors/indigo';
import pink from '@material-ui/core/colors/pink';
import red from '@material-ui/core/colors/red';

const myTheme = merge({}, defaultTheme, {
    palette: {
        primary: indigo,
        secondary: pink,
        error: red,
        contrastThreshold: 3,
        tonalOffset: 0.2,
    },
    typography: {
        // Use the system font instead of the default Roboto font.
        fontFamily: ['-apple-system', 'BlinkMacSystemFont', '"Segoe UI"', 'Arial', 'sans-serif'].join(','),
    },
    overrides: {
        MuiButton: { // override the styles of all instances of this component
            root: { // Name of the rule
                color: 'white', // Some CSS
            },
        },
    },
});
```

You can find more information at https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Theming.html#writing-a-custom-theme, and a complete example of custom admin theme in the e-commerce demo (https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/examples/demo/src/layout/themes.ts).